# How to create animated explosion in QT

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I'm creating space shooter game and want to add some special effects:) I mean, when bullet hits the target, enemy will explode.
I have a few pictures (steps) of explosion, also I'm using QGraphicsPixmapItem class and setPixmap() method to set pixmap of Enemy.
My bullet and enemy class:

bullet.h

```
#ifndef BULLET_H
#define BULLET_H

#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

class Bullet : public QPropertyAnimation, public QGraphicsPixmapItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Bullet(QGraphicsItem * parent=0);
    static int howManyKilled() { return killed; }
    static int howManyMissed() { return missed; }
    static void resetStats() { killed = 0; missed = 0; } // to avoid bad multipler calculate
    void setAccurancy() { accurancy = killed/missed * 100; }
    static double accurancyInPercentage() { return accurancy; }
public slots:
    void move();
private:
    static int killed;
    static int missed;
    static double accurancy;
};

#endif // BULLET_H
```

bullet.cpp

```
#include "Bullet.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QList>
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <typeinfo>
#include "levels.h"

extern Game * game; // there is an external global object called game
int Bullet::killed = 0;
int Bullet::missed = 0;
double Bullet::accurancy = 0;

Bullet::Bullet(QGraphicsItem *parent): QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent){
    // draw graphics
    setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/res/images/bullets/bullet.png"));
    missed++; // increse missed when bullet is created

    // make/connect a timer to move() the bullet every so often
    QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));

    // start the timer
    timer->start(3);
}
/*
void Bullet::explosion()
{
    setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/res/images/effects/explosion/1_12.png"));
}
*/
void Bullet::move(){
    // get a list of all the items currently colliding with this bullet
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> colliding_items = collidingItems();

    // if one of the colliding items is an Enemy, destroy both the bullet and the enemy
    for (int i = 0, n = colliding_items.size(); i < n; ++i){
        if (typeid(*(colliding_items[i])) == typeid(Enemy)){
            // increase the score
            game->score->increase();

            //play explosion animation
            //Bullet::explosion();
            //QTimer::singleShot()
            //explosion = new QPropertyAnimation(this);
            //explosion->setDuration(300);
            //explosion->


            // remove them from the scene (still on the heap)
            scene()->removeItem(colliding_items[i]);
            scene()->removeItem(this);

            // delete them from the heap to save memory
            delete colliding_items[i];
            delete this;

            killed++;
            missed--; // decrese missed if bullet colide with enemy
            if((killed+1) % 9 == 0)
            {
                game->level->Levels::incrementLevels();
                game->score->Score::addToSum(); /// TODO
            }

            //qDebug() << "Already killed: " << killed;
            //qDebug() << "Already missed: " << missed;
            // return (all code below refers to a non existint bullet)
            return;
        }
    }

    // if there was no collision with an Enemy, move the bullet forward
    setPos(x(),y()-1);
    // if the bullet is off the screen, destroy it
    if (pos().y() < 0){
        scene()->removeItem(this);
        delete this;
    }
}
```

enemy.h

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H

#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

class Enemy: public QObject,public QGraphicsPixmapItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Enemy(QGraphicsItem * parent=0);
public slots:
    void move();
};

#endif // ENEMY_H
```

enemy.cpp

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QList>
#include <stdlib.h> // rand()
#include <ctime>
#include "Game.h"
#include "hp.h"
#include <typeinfo>

extern Game * game;
extern unsigned int width;
extern unsigned int height;

Enemy::Enemy(QGraphicsItem *parent): QObject(), QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent){
    //set random x position
    //srand( time( NULL ) );
    int random_number = rand()% (width-200) + 100;
    //qDebug() << random_number;
    setPos(random_number,0);

    // drew the rect
    setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/res/images/enemies/3.png"));
    setTransformOriginPoint(50,50);
    //setRotation(180);

    // make/connect a timer to move() the enemy every so often
    QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));

    // start the timer
    timer->start(10);
}

void Enemy::move(){
    ///////////////////////// COLISIONS /////////////////////////////////////
    // get a list of all the items currently colliding with this bullet
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> colliding_items = collidingItems();

    // if one of the colliding items is an Enemy, destroy both the bullet and the enemy
    for (int i = 0, n = colliding_items.size(); i < n; ++i){
        if (typeid(*(colliding_items[i])) == typeid(Player)){
            // increase the score
            game->hp->decrementLives();

            // remove them from the scene (still on the heap)
            scene()->removeItem(this);

            // delete them from the heap to save memory
            delete this;

            // return (all code below refers to a non existint bullet)
            return;
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // if there was no collision with an Enemy, move the bullet forward
    // move enemy down

    if (Levels::howManyLevels() < 10)
    {
        setPos(x(),y() + Levels::howManyLevels());
    }
    else
    {
        setPos(x(),y() + 10);
    }

    // destroy enemy when it goes out of the screen
    if (pos().y() > height){
        //decrease the health
        game->hp->decrementLives();

        scene()->removeItem(this);
        delete this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When bullet colide with enemy i want to change pixmap of enemy to explosion_step1, then to step2, etc. Is there any helpful qt class to do that? I was figuring out with QPropertyAnimation but with no result.

Comment: If you have predefined set of images then probably the classes from Qt won't fit you well. Create your own Explosion class which will contain all the pixmaps of explosion. When collision is detected you will create an object of the class at the point. Inside class you ll replace the current image for painting and use timer for delay between images display.

Comment: What about Q3Canvas?